# How to convert a nil string in swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

I try to filter just the name of my peripheral.name object. Usually, that's no problem. For example:
`[Optional"Apple TV"]` works like it should.
But if I get a nil object, I get a fatal error and I don't understand why...

```
let str = "\(peripheral.name)"
let test_str = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start:str.startIndex.advancedBy(10), end: str.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)))   
print(test_str)
```

I thought that the operation `"\(peripheral.name)"` converts every object into a string... also a nil type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` will always be a String indeed: if `peripheral.name` is nil, it will result in an empty string.

But you're using `advancedBy` with hardcoded values like 10: it won't work on an empty string, that's the source of your fatal error, you can't move along an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, is there any possibility to get the string like this: [Optional"nil"]??

Comment: Or I proof if the string is empty... that will work! thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you want to avoid this error, the correct way would be to check for the string length first. :)

Comment: Am I right that there is either an empty string or a string in this [Optional" "] struct? because if the string isn't empty, I will get every time the additional charcters.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're referring to with `[Optional" "]`. Are we talking about string vs optional string? If you get `Optional("my string")` instead of `"my string"` it means you have to unwrap it first (with `if let` for example).

Comment: Ahh I think I made a mistake with the stored string in my array and the shown string with the prinf() method... So if I get a vaild string of this let str = "\(peripheral.name)" I store only Apple TV but it shows [Optional"Apple TV"]. Is there any possibility to output only the raw string?

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. Please could you show me just the *exact* output of `println(str)` so that I can help you? Thanks. :)

Comment: I get this: [Optional"Apple TV"] sorry if it is a little hard to understand ;)

Comment: No problem, it's just that I didn't understand why there were brackets around your string. For what you just pasted it looks like `str` from `"\(peripheral.name)"` is actually an array?! I'm indeed lost here. ;) Don't hesitate to post a new question showing the way you're creating your values so that me/someone can help you accurately, the comments aren't a convenient place for that. :)

Comment: sorry you are right, I have stored the strings in an array :/ I will ask a new question in the evening! Thanks for your time